# React Native iOS app showing blank screen after launch screen - How to fix?

Tags: ios, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to complete a hybrid react native app for android and ios. It is working fine in android. But when I try to run ios app in simulator or device then

1. It hows the ios launch screen and then a blank screen comes and nothing happens. My splash screen should have come after launch screen
2. in the logs it shows the console logs from componentdidmount in my splash sceen. Which means that the splashscreen was loaded properly as expected but I see only blank screen. following is the code of splashscreen:

```
componentDidMount = async() =>{

    const {navigation} = this.props;
    var token = ''
    console.log("here start");
    await AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then(res=>{
        
        console.log('token', res)
        token = res;
        })

    // this.unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', (token) => {
    //         console.log('check token', token)
            setTimeout(()=>{
                if(token!='' && token!=null){
                    console.log('check 1')
                    navigation.navigate('language')
                }else{ console.log('check 2')
                    navigation.navigate('language')
                }
            
            }, 2000);
        //   });

   }
```

render method in splashscreen:

```
render() {
        //const {navigation} = this.props;
        return(
          <SafeAreaView style = {SplashScreenStyle.MainContainer}>
            <View style={this.styles.container}>
                <ImageBackground source={require('../assets/images/SplashScreenBackground.png')} resizeMode="cover" style={SplashScreenStyle.backgroundImage}>
                  <View style={{textAlign:'center', padding:20}}>
                  <Image  source={require('../assets/images/splash.png')}></Image>
                    
                  </View>
                   
                    <Image 
                    // style={this.styles.itmlogo} 
                    style={{
                        resizeMode: 'cover',
                        position: 'absolute',
                        bottom: 20,
                        width: 86,
                    }}
                    source={require('../assets/images/itm-logo.png')}></Image>
                    {/* <Text style={this.styles.text}>
                        TIMOR-LESTE
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={this.styles.text}>
                        Emergency Response System
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={this.styles.text}>
                        ( T E R S )
                    </Text>            */}
                </ImageBackground>
            </View>
          </SafeAreaView>
        ); 
    }
```

I thought it to be a css issue and so removed style from both safeareaview and view tags but nothing changed.

Also I changed render method and return a plain text but that also did not come.